# SQL Gather Data from the same column with possible different results

Tags: sql, mariadb

The problem I am currently experiencing is that if the Contact.email are different then it displays both as NULL.  If I use OR instead of AND it acquires both of the emails but in different rows, so they are duplicated.

I think that I need to assign the alias but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
SELECT Item.brought, Contact.email AS SalesContact, Contact.email AS TechContact
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Contact
ON Item.sales_id = Contact_id
AND Item.tech_id = Contact_id;
```

What I am trying to do is associate the Item.brought with the two possible email address which as stored in a different table.
Any advice would be greatly predicated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Add sample table data, the current result and the expected result. All as well formatted text.

Comment: MariaDB and running the SQL through MySQL Workbench, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why would he need to give us data? It is perfectly clear that he is joining a guy if and only if he is the sales guy and the tech guy of the item at the same time, which is a minority. Instead, he needs to join separately to the two contacts, which will handle the special case when they are the same as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the same email. You need to join twice to Contact, like this:

```
SELECT Item.brought, SC.email AS SalesContact, TC.email AS TechContact
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Contact SC
ON Item.sales_id = SC.Contact_id
LEFT JOIN Contact TC
ON Item.tech_id = TC.Contact_id;
```

Explanation: You need two `Contact` records, which are not necessarily the same, since you can imagine a tech who is not also on sales and a sales who is not also a tech. So you are joining the sales guy using `Item.sales_id` and the tech guy using `Item.tech_id`.